# How to debug kernel code without running kernel?

Tags: gcc, linux-kernel

I'm reading some kernel books, I want to debug the `spinlock_t` usage, and prepared the following demo code:

```
////////////////////////////
// demo/spinlock.c
////////////////////////////

#include <linux/spinlock.h>

struct obj {
    spinlock_t spinlock;
}

int demo0() {
    struct obj o;
    spin_lock_init(o.spinlock);
}

int main(){
    demo0();
}
```

The Makefile seems like:

```
######################
# demo/Makefile
######################

demo: spinlock.c
    gcc -o spinlock spinlock.c -I../linux-5.6.9/arch/x86/include -I../linux-5.6.9/include
```

The file tree seems like this

```
├── demo
└── linux-5.6.9
```

While `meke`, it gave me tones of errors (too many, I can't enumerate them here), It seems like that I missed some GCC CFLAGS or others.

How to debug kernel code line by line? Most of Google results are GDB/Qemu debugging within running kernel. Is there any suggestions to debug the kernel code without running the kernel?

Comment: You can't possibly run `gcc` directly and expect it to work. The proper way to compile kernel code is through correct invocation of `make` passing the kernel `Makefile`. See [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61678727/3889449).

Comment: You did tons of mistakes there, that's why. a) Linux kernel modules are not build in usual way; b) there is no meaning of `main()` since there is no C library; c) you missed function parameters  and return values; d) you missed difference between pointer and object, e) ...and so on... (seems c) and d) due to C++ influence or so).