# single kernel module compile without i386 headers?

Tags: kernel, kernel-module

I'm trying to compile the snd-usb-audio module on hiveos (kernel 5.4.0)

by doing

```
make -C . M=sound/usb
```

But it gives

> Make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'sound/usb/card.o', needed by 'sound/usb/snd-usb-audio.o'.  Stop.

The standard module compiling approach 'make scripts / prepare' etc fails with

> make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/x86/tools/relocs_32.c',
> needed by 'arch/x86/tools/relocs_32.o'.  Stop.
>
> arch/x86/Makefile:235: recipe for target 'archscripts' failed
>
> make: *** [archscripts] Error 2

apt searching for i386 headers fails, because i386 headers aren't provided

Is there a workaround to compile one single module directly without i386 headers ?

Comment: "Is there a workaround to compile one single module directly without i386 headers?" - No, there is no such way. See e.g. [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61670100/how-to-compile-linux-kernel-module-without-kernel-makefile). Note, that "linux kernel headers" contains not only header files, but e.g. `Modules.symvers` file which can be obtained only during the building the linux kernel. Without that file no module can be built.

Comment: You quite likely missed the preparation step. Or if the kernel is from distro, you should point `-C` to that directory rather than yours.